# Troubleshooting Oracle Java 7 with Firefox

Tags: firefox, java, plugins, oracle

I run Ubuntu 13.04 with up-to-date Firefox and Oracle Java 7 is installed from the package `oracle-java7-installer` from the `ppa:webupd8team/java` PPA.

Java doesn't work in Firefox.

When I start firefox from the command line, and open a webpage with some java, the java applet doesn't work and in the terminal firefox prints:

```
$ firefox

(process:28565): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion `sys_page_size == 0' failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java": error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
    at sun.plugin2.jvm.JVMLauncher.start(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.server.JVMInstance.startImpl(Unknown Source)
(and some 20-30 lines more)
```

(I guess the GLib-line can be ignored here.)

Also, when I close the tab that contained the java applet, firefox freezes and I have to kill it.

However, the permissions look fine:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5746 Jul 22 17:35 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java
```

So, what could be wrong here? What to check next?

Comment: Any reason not to use the OpenJDK 7 from the Ubuntu Software Center? It is easier with that.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the exact same problem running Ubuntu Precise.  I'm running Proxmox on a server, and their java viewer requires Oracle java and does not work with icedtea.  I installed the latest java 7 from http://www.webupd8.org, but could not get it to work with Firefox.  I did discover that java did work in the Opera browser.

When I saw your message and saw the issue with permissions, I thought ahhah! apparmor.  Sure enough the kern.log shows:

```
/var/log/kern.log

Aug  1 09:54:50 laptop kernel: [42653.495082] type=1400 audit(1375368890.811:81): apparmor="DENIED" operation="exec" parent=22495 profile="/usr/lib/firefox/firefox{,*[^s][^h]}" name="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java" pid=22507 comm="plugin-containe" requested_mask="x" denied_mask="x" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Aug  1 09:56:38 laptop kernel: [42761.283499] type=1400 audit(1375368998.599:82): apparmor="DENIED" operation="exec" parent=22812 profile="/usr/lib/firefox/firefox{,*[^s][^h]}" name="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java" pid=22824 comm="plugin-containe" requested_mask="x" denied_mask="x" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Aug  1 10:11:51 laptop kernel: [43674.436828] type=1400 audit(1375369911.752:83): apparmor="DENIED" operation="exec" parent=23255 profile="/usr/lib/firefox/firefox{,*[^s][^h]}" name="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java" pid=23267 comm="plugin-containe" requested_mask="x" denied_mask="x" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
```

I set apparmor to complain mode

```
sudo aa-complain /usr/bin/firefox
sudo service apparmor reload
```

and it started working

Then when I reset apparmor to enforce mode

```
sudo aa-enforce /usr/bin/firefox
sudo service apparmor reload
```

it unexpectedly continued to work.  I suspect the apparmor reload cleared a cache file that wasn't getting cleared by the many reboots I've done while looking for the cause.

Addition: After playing around awhile, I found that processes started in complain mode, remain in complain mode even after the profile is switched to enforce mode.

Update the apparmor profile for firefox (or other browsers) in /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ubuntu-browsers.d/java

```
# Under Java plugin, add two lines:
  /usr/lib/jvm/java-*-oracle/jre/bin/java{,_vm} cx -> browser_java,
  /usr/lib/jvm/java-*-oracle/jre/lib/*/libnp*.so cx -> browser_java,
# before the lines:
  /usr/lib/jvm/java-*-sun-1.*/jre/bin/java{,_vm} cx -> browser_java,
  /usr/lib/jvm/java-*-sun-1.*/jre/lib/*/libnp*.so cx -> browser_java,

# In the browser_java profile, add two lines:
  /usr/lib/jvm/java-*-oracle/jre/bin/java{,_vm} ix,
  /usr/lib/jvm/java-*-oracle/jre/lib/i386/client/classes.jsa m,
# before the lines:
  /usr/lib/jvm/java-*-sun-1.*/jre/bin/java{,_vm} ix,
  /usr/lib/jvm/java-*-sun-1.*/jre/lib/i386/client/classes.jsa m,
```

Then restart apparmor:

```
sudo service apparmor restart
```

When testing, I found it was necessary to reload or restart apparmor after each profile change and then restart the browser.  Several times I was fooled into thinking a change was working only to have it fail after a few hours. I'm still receiving a few apparmor messages when running the java browser test, but none seem to prevent it from working.

Comment: Thank you. Was trying all sorts of solutions which did not work. This did the trick.